# How to run tilemill remotely via the web interface (ubuntu)

Tags: tilemill

I have set up tilemill on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine using the commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:developmentseed/mapbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tilemill
service tilemill start
```

Now I was able to access tilemill on `http://localhost:20009`. But whenever I tried
to access tilemill functions on the same machine using its IP from my other computer,
I get an error saying

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at HOST_ADDRESS:20009
```

I have checked that firewall isn't an issue because other other ports such as 8080 hosted on the same server can be accessed correctly.

Any idea how to enable access to tilemill from a different computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually configure Tilemill to accept remote connections - by default they are blocked, regardless of firewall configuration. Edit your Tilemill config file (~/tilemill/config.json) and add:

```
"listenHost": "0.0.0.0"
"coreUrl": "<TILEMILL_HOST>:20009",
"tileUrl": "<TILEMILL_HOST>:20008",
"server": true
```

(Replacing  with your hostname or IP address). Additional instructions are available here: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/ubuntu-service/